# Protect my user account with a password for UAC prompts without using a user password?

Tags: windows-10, passwords, uac

I want the computer to ask me for a password when a new software is installed or changes are made, but I don't want the

Comment: "but I don't want the" - Please finish this sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is an administrator account with a password (be sure of this), then make a User Account without a password. Now when you install software, you will be challenged for the Admin Password.